# AttributeError: type object 'TabularDataset' has no attribute 'name'

Tags: torchtext

import spacy
label_field = Field(sequential=False, use_vocab=False, batch_first=True)
text_field = Field(tokenize='spacy', lower=True, include_lengths=True, batch_first=True)
fields = [('label', label_field), ('title', text_field)]

## TabularDataset

train, valid, test = TabularDataset.splits(train='train.xlsx', validation='valid.xlsx', test='test.xlsx',format='xlsx', fields=fields, skip_header=True)

I really can't solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to define the path，and everything would be fine!

```
train,dev,test=data.TabularDataset.splits(path = './', train='train.tsv',validation='dev.tsv', test='test.tsv',skip_header=True, fields=[('label',label_field),('text',text_field)], format='tsv')
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to make the code more clear, specially by formatting it ? StackOverflow use Markdown system, you can also see help on the right when you edit edit :)

Comment: Appreciate your advice